# Facing issue while updating auto increment counter value in react.js using useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having an issue with the auto-increment counter, which updates every 2 secs. It updates the value but in a glitchy way Please check the code and share your views regarding the problem.

```
 const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1200)
 function handleCounter() {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (counter => 1200 && counter < 1364) {
        setInterval(handleCounter, 2000);
    }else {
        clearInterval(setInterval(handleCounter, 2000))
    }
    clearInterval(setInterval(handleCounter, 2000))
}, [counter])
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/do with `clearInterval(setInterval(...))`?

Comment: I'm trying to create a counter which would update or increment value by 1 after every 2 secs.

Comment: Every time you do `setInterval()`, you're creating a new interval. Doing `clearInterval(setInterval(...))` doesn't clear the previously created interval, such as the one in your if-statement, see the docs for [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) on its correct usage. You also don't want to run the `useEffect()` each time `counter` changes, and this will end up creating multiple intervals if you don't clear them. You should only create the interval once on mount, and then use `setCounter(counter => counter + 1)` to avoid closure issues on `counter`

Comment: (a) greater or equal is `>=` **not** `=>` (b) what is the significance of `1200` and `1364`? (c) `clearInterval(setInterval(...))` is effectively a no-op. (d) the only interval that you don't clear is the very first one in your code, and you never clear it, so, every time your effect is called, you're piling another interval into the mix...

Comment: Read, absorb, borrow code from here: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ . It's the definitive article about timers and React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
      counter < 1364 && setCounter((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    };
  }, [counter]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will execute the handleCounter function every 2 seconds. Is it what you are trying to do?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => handleCounter(), 2000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  },[]);
```

Comment: OP would also need to change `setCounter(counter + 1)` to `setCounter(counter => counter + 1)` to avoid the closure on `counter` in `handleCounter`